# FileSystemWatcher with specifying a datetime?

Tags: c#

I want to specify the FileSystemWatcher to check the files in the system has changed since a datetime:

```
FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();

watcher.Path = @"C:\MyDirectory";
watcher.Changed+= new RenamedEventHandler(watcher_Changed)
watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

How can I specify it such that: when the watcher is started, there are already existing files inside the folder. The fileSystemWatcher will get notified for the files are after a specific date time. how is it implemented with FileSystemWatcher? or if not, what is other alternatives?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can find the details of this here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx

Comment: devn I have added an example of the Missing Events that you are looking for as well as 3 other events that you could check if you care to check those

Comment: Thanks all. I am looking for something like this: NotifyFilters.CreationTime.CompareTo(                                                     DateTime.Parse(lastDateTime)) > 0; but it seems it does not work. I want to check the existing files in a folder as well

Comment: @devn - You'll have to check existing files manually because they don't trigger the `FileSystemWatcher` events. You can use `Directory.EnumerateFiles` for that with a `Where` filter similar to the NotifyFilters code in your comment.

Comment: Tell me if I understand you correctly. You want to be notified by FileSystemWatcher only if certain files dated after a specific date changes?

Comment: when I start FileSystemWatcher, it should start to check the files existing inside first then go processing if there is new file created. probably. @M.Babcock is correct.

Comment: FileSystemWatcher does NOT check existing files.  You will have to do that manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it:

before watching a folder using watcher.Notify, I have to check all of the files inside a folder if they are new then process them first.

Answer (score 1):

here is a snippet of what you can try .. you can also look at the link here as well MSDN for Code Examples
[FileWatcher MSDN Documentation and Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.changed%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

```
watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite 
           | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
        // Only watch text files.
        watcher.Filter = "*.txt";

        // Add event handlers.
        watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnRenamed);

        // Begin watching.
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```